# Binding periodically updated data array to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a valueArray[125] coming from UDP socket and array is being updated every 20ms. And i want to display every member of this array in data grid view. So far, i can display the array on the grid view, but i have a couple of problems:

1- There is no scrollbar on the gridview, so i only can see first 15-20 data in the form.

2- The datagridview is blinking because of the refreshing proccess.

And lastly i want add one more column right next to the "Data" column, so that i can see the index of the array. This is what i've done so far:

```
public void UpdateGridView(byte[] valueArray)
    {
        dataGridView.Visible = false;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Data");

        for (int j = 0; j < 125; j++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                row[i] = valueArray[j];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        }
        dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
        dataGridView.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms?

Comment: The blink is likely due to (re)setting the datasource *in* the loop.

Comment: Oh sorry, i must have forgot to say WinForms. Should i set it just once ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes i have indeed, but i must have forgotten to post my answer to here. It seems like accessing rows and columns by using their names is easier than accesing them by their indexes. So i changed my solution a bit more. First i filled the whole grid with zeros on the form load, and then in the UpgradeGridView function i changed the values directly by using their names.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread ReceiveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ReceiveUDPData));
        comboBox1.Items.Add("04 : Read Input Registers");
        ReceiveThread.IsBackground = true;
        ReceiveThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
        ReceiveThread.Start();
        Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;

        dt.Columns.Add("Index");
        dt.Columns.Add("Data");
        for (int j = 0; j < 125; j++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row[0] = j;
            row[1] = 0;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
        }
        dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    }

public void UpdateGridView(byte[] valueArray)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < valueArray.Length; j++)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.Rows[j];
            row["Index"] = j+1; 
            row["Data"] = valueArray[j];
        }
    }
```

To be honest, i still didn't get how it works exactly, but i did lack of time back then, and this helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The flicker comes from continuosly hiding and showing the `DGV`.

Here is a version without flicker which includes an extra column to show the index:

```
public void UpdateGridView(byte[] valueArray)
{
    //  dataGridView.Visible = false;     // < ==
    dataGridView.SuspendLayout();         // < ==
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt.Columns.Add("Index");             // < ==
    dt.Columns.Add("Data");

    for (int j = 0; j < valueArray.Length; j++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = j;                      // < ==
        row[1] = valueArray[j];          // < ==
        //for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)    // < ==
        //{                              // < ==
        //    row[i] = valueArray[j];    // < ==
        //}                              // < ==
        dt.Rows.Add(row)
       // dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    }
    dataGridView.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView.ResumeLayout();         // < ==
    //   dataGridView.Visible = true;    // < ==
}
```

By default the `DataGridView` will show both `ScrollBars`. If your doesn't, you have switched them off. To restore use the designer or code like this:

```
dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Both;  // or..
dataGridView.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
```

Comment: if i don't do hide and show the grid, the famous "huge red X mark" appears on my grid after a couple of seconds.

And when i apply your snippet to my form, i don't know why but the grid disappear.

Comment: I have tested the code and here it worked fine with a 50ms timer. So if the DGV seems to disappear, could it be that you are still hiding it somwhere or have not done all the changes in the code??

Comment: I guess so, so i need to check my form properties, and then i'll tell you the result. And really thanks for your helps!